# Parsing Character String in R

Tags: r, parsing, char, expression

I want to parse a character vector in R in a dataframe constructed similarily to the one below:

```
a <- c("abc def. ghi jkl mno pqr", "stu vwx.", "yza bcd. efg hij mno klm", " nop qrs.", "tuv wxy.")
b <- c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE)
df <- as.data.frame(cbind(a, b))
df$a <- as.character(df$a)
df$b <- as.logical(df$b)

df
                         a     b
1 abc def. ghi jkl mno pqr  TRUE
2                 stu vwx. FALSE
3 yza bcd. efg hij mno klm  TRUE
4                 nop qrs. FALSE
5                 tuv wxy. FALSE
> str(df)
'data.frame':   5 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ a: chr  "abc def. ghi jkl mno pqr" "stu vwx." "yza bcd. efg hij mno klm" " nop qrs." ...
 $ b: logi  TRUE FALSE TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

I want to create a new variable, `c`, that returns `NA` in all cases where `df$b == FALSE` and, in all cases where `df$b == TRUE`, returns the two words that appear immediately prior to `mno`. As it happens, in all cases, these two desired words are sandwiched between `mno` and a period (`.`). I would ultimately like `df$c` to look like:

```
> c
[1] "ghi jkl" NA        "efg hij" NA       
[5] NA       
> str(c)
 chr [1:5] "ghi jkl" NA "efg hij" NA NA
```

I've been able to extract the words between two keywords using:

```
df$c <- ifelse(df$b == TRUE, str_sub(str_extract(df$a, "(?<=\\bdef).+?.(\\bmno)")), NA)

df
                            a     b
1    abc def. ghi jkl mno pqr  TRUE
2                    stu vwx. FALSE
3 yzab cdef. ghi jkl mno mnop  TRUE
4                    qrs tuv. FALSE
5                    wxy zab. FALSE
              c
1 . ghi jkl mno
2          <NA>
3          <NA>
4          <NA>
5          <NA>
```

But it does not work with punctuation:

```
df$c <- ifelse(df$b == TRUE, str_sub(str_extract(df$a, "(?<=\\b.).+?.(\\bmno)"), end = -5L), NA)

df
                            a     b
1    abc def. ghi jkl mno pqr  TRUE
2                    stu vwx. FALSE
3 yzab cdef. ghi jkl mno mnop  TRUE
4                    qrs tuv. FALSE
5                    wxy zab. FALSE
                  c
1   bc def. ghi jkl
2              <NA>
3 zab cdef. ghi jkl
4              <NA>
5              <NA>
```

I am somewhat new to R, and don't fully understand general exressions. How do I call just the two words between `.` and `mno`?

Thanks for your help!

**EDIT**

I've also tried to count words backwards from `mno` using `gsub` with:

```
> df$c <- ifelse(df$b == TRUE, gsub("(\\w+\\s)*(\\w+)\\smno.*","\\1\\2", df$a), NA)
> df
                            a     b
1    abc def. ghi jkl mno pqr  TRUE
2                    stu vwx. FALSE
3 yzab cdef. ghi jkl mno mnop  TRUE
4                    qrs tuv. FALSE
5                    wxy zab. FALSE
                   c
1   abc def. ghi jkl
2               <NA>
3 yzab cdef. jkl mno
4               <NA>
5               <NA>
```

Though this has worked for me in the past, here it seems to just return everything before `mno`. I've also been able to trim my results in the past using `start =` and `end =`, but here I would need to count words, as opposed to characters, to utilize that approach. Is there a way to trim my results by counting words instead of by counting characters?

Comment: If it's the case that `b` is true iff there's a regex match, there's `transform(df, c = sapply(regmatches(a, regexec(".*?(\\w+ \\w+) mno .*", a)), \`[\`, 2))`

Answer (score 3):

We can use `sub` to match characters (`.*`), capture two instances of word followed by zero or more spaces as a group followed by space and 'mno', then replace with the backreference, use this in `ifelse` to FALSE values with NA

```
df$c <-  with(df, ifelse(b, sub(".*\\b(\\w+\\s+\\w+)\\s+mno\\b.*", "\\1", a), NA))

df$c
#[1] "ghi jkl" NA        "efg hij" NA        NA
```

Or as @Frank mentioned, `replace` can be used as well

```
with(df, replace(sub(".*\\b(\\w+\\s+\\w+)\\s+mno\\b.*", "\\1", a), !b, NA))
```

Comment: Thanks for your help `@Frank` and `@akun`. I appreciate your insights.
 However, I seem to be getting different results than you did: `> df$c <- with(df, ifelse(b, sub(".*\\b((\\w+\\s*){2})\\smno\\b.*", "\\1", a), NA))
> df$c
[1] "jkl" NA    "hij" NA    NA `. Any idea why I'm getting only the second of the two words you are? @Frank's solution worked on my sample data set; but, on my real data set, I got the following error: `Error: unexpected '=' in "transform(superbowl, superbowl$Fumbler ="` where `df == superbowl` and `df$c == superbowl$Fumbler`. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @DataProphets  Not sure what happened.  I edited my first option to a compact one (if I remember it was working - did you changed your example any way)?.  I reverted back to the earlier regex.  It is working for the example